# xsd error message: "The content type of a derived type and that of its base must both be mixed or both be element-only."

Tags: xml, xsd, sequence

Consider the following xml schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.0" vc:maxVersion="1.1">


    <xs:element name="zoo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/> 
                <xs:element name="zootier" type="tier" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>



    <xs:complexType name="tier">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/> 
            <xs:element name="alter" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="säugetier_ct">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tier">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="tragezeit" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>  
                </xs:sequence>   
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="pferd_ct">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tier">
                    <xs:attribute name="schimmel" type="xs:boolean"/>              
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="katze_ct">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="fellfarbe" type="xs:string"/>  
            </xs:sequence>   
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="vogel_ct">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tier">
                <xs:attribute name="flugfaehig" type="xs:boolean"/>                   
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="gans_ct">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tier">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="schlachtgewicht" type="xs:double"/>  
                </xs:sequence>            
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="fink_ct">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="beringt" type="xs:boolean"/>   
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>



    <xs:complexType name="pfleger">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="pflegt" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="tier" type="xs:IDREF"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>



    <xs:complexType name="behausung_ct">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:sequence>  
            <xs:element name="zootier" type="tier" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>      
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="gebäude_ct">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="behausung_ct">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="flaeche" type="xs:double"/> 
                </xs:sequence>     
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="teich_ct">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="behausung_ct">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="wassertiefe" type="xs:double"/> 
                </xs:sequence>  
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>



</xs:schema>
```

This gives me the following error messages:

```
Error1: The content of 'katze_ct' is invalid.  Element 'sequence' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Error2: The content of 'fink_ct' is invalid.  Element 'sequence' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Error3: The content of 'behausung_ct' is invalid.  Element 'sequence' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Error 4: The content type of a derived type and that of its base must both be mixed or both be element-only. Type 'gebäude_ct' is element only, but its base type is not.

Error 5: The content type of a derived type and that of its base must both be mixed or both be element-only. Type 'teich_ct' is element only, but its base type is not.
```

Errors 1-3 are of the same type. Errors 4 and 5 are also of the same type.
With respect to errors 4+5: Why would the derived type have to have the same kind of content as the parent type? This can't be part of xml schema rules ... it would be nonsensical. What if the extended class only has one additional element compared to the parent class (which consists, say, of elements and attributes). Would I have to invent some attribute for the derived class just to make the two classes similar?

I simply don't get what's wrong in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors 1-3 make sense, 4-5 are spurious. Perhaps they will go away when you fix the first three. It's not unusual for compilers to go down strange paths when trying to continue after finding errors.

Using Saxon to validate the schema, I got errors for katze_ct and fink_ct which can be fixed by removing the spurious complexContent element:

```
<xs:complexType name="katze_ct">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="fellfarbe" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

and an error for behausing_ct because the xs:attribute is misplaced, it should be:

```
<xs:complexType name="behausung_ct">      
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="zootier" type="tier" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
```

With those changes the schema now compiles.

The rules that an element-only type can't extend a mixed type, or vice versa, are perfectly sensible rules but you aren't violating them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It's now validating.